# How to apply texture to glutSolidCube

Tags: opengl, glut, textures

I can find tutorials about mapping textures to polygons specifying vertices etc. but nothing regarding how to apply a texture to a cube (or other stuff) drawn with glut (glutSolidCube).

I am doing something like:

```
glTexEnvfv(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, decal);
glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, repeat);
glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, repeat);
glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, nearest);
glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, nearest);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, myImageWidth, myImageHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)myImage);

//...

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//now draw the cube
glutSolidCube(N);
```

Doing this I get the texture to apply to the cube but the whole cube gets the color of the first byte in the texture!

Is there any way of mapping a texture to a solid cube (and other solids) when using glutSolidCube?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, since `glutSolidCube()` does not generate texture coordinates.  Fortunately, though, `glutSolidCube()` is easy to implement yourself and add texture coordinates.  Here's the source code to `glutSolidCube()` and associated functions, from http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/:

```
/* Copyright (c) Mark J. Kilgard, 1994, 1997. */

/**                                                                             
(c) Copyright 1993, Silicon Graphics, Inc.                                      

ALL RIGHTS RESERVED                                                             

Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software                   
for any purpose and without fee is hereby granted, provided                     
that the above copyright notice appear in all copies and that                   
both the copyright notice and this permission notice appear in                  
supporting documentation, and that the name of Silicon                          
Graphics, Inc. not be used in advertising or publicity                          
pertaining to distribution of the software without specific,                    
written prior permission.

THE MATERIAL EMBODIED ON THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED TO YOU
"AS-IS" AND WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS, IMPLIED OR
OTHERWISE, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION, ANY WARRANTY OF
MERCHANTABILITY OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  IN NO
EVENT SHALL SILICON GRAPHICS, INC.  BE LIABLE TO YOU OR ANYONE
ELSE FOR ANY DIRECT, SPECIAL, INCIDENTAL, INDIRECT OR
CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OF ANY KIND, OR ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER,
INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION, LOSS OF PROFIT, LOSS OF USE,
SAVINGS OR REVENUE, OR THE CLAIMS OF THIRD PARTIES, WHETHER OR
NOT SILICON GRAPHICS, INC.  HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY
OF SUCH LOSS, HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY,
ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE POSSESSION, USE OR
PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.

US Government Users Restricted Rights

Use, duplication, or disclosure by the Government is subject to
restrictions set forth in FAR 52.227.19(c)(2) or subparagraph
(c)(1)(ii) of the Rights in Technical Data and Computer
Software clause at DFARS 252.227-7013 and/or in similar or
successor clauses in the FAR or the DOD or NASA FAR
Supplement.  Unpublished-- rights reserved under the copyright
laws of the United States.  Contractor/manufacturer is Silicon
Graphics, Inc., 2011 N.  Shoreline Blvd., Mountain View, CA
94039-7311.

OpenGL(TM) is a trademark of Silicon Graphics, Inc.
*/

static void
drawBox(GLfloat size, GLenum type)
{
  static GLfloat n[6][3] =
  {
    {-1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {0.0, -1.0, 0.0},
    {0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
    {0.0, 0.0, -1.0}
  };
  static GLint faces[6][4] =
  {
    {0, 1, 2, 3},
    {3, 2, 6, 7},
    {7, 6, 5, 4},
    {4, 5, 1, 0},
    {5, 6, 2, 1},
    {7, 4, 0, 3}
  };
  GLfloat v[8][3];
  GLint i;

  v[0][0] = v[1][0] = v[2][0] = v[3][0] = -size / 2;
  v[4][0] = v[5][0] = v[6][0] = v[7][0] = size / 2;
  v[0][1] = v[1][1] = v[4][1] = v[5][1] = -size / 2;
  v[2][1] = v[3][1] = v[6][1] = v[7][1] = size / 2;
  v[0][2] = v[3][2] = v[4][2] = v[7][2] = -size / 2;
  v[1][2] = v[2][2] = v[5][2] = v[6][2] = size / 2;

  for (i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
    glBegin(type);
    glNormal3fv(&n[i][0]);
    glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][0]][0]);
    glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][1]][0]);
    glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][2]][0]);
    glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][3]][0]);
    glEnd();
  }
}

void APIENTRY
glutSolidCube(GLdouble size)
{
  drawBox(size, GL_QUADS);
}
```

Just add in some calls to the [glTexCoord*](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/gl/texcoord.html) family of functions.  [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06) has a good tutorial on how to get started with texture mapping with OpenGL.

Comment: sounds great - any suggestion or useful link about how to add the glTexCoord stuff (never done it before)?

Comment: @JohnIdol, it really depends on how you want your textures to be mapped. Do you want a vexel at each vertex? Do you want certain faces to have a different orientation/rotation? You could easily add glTexCoord's with (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0) as the (u, v) (?) values before each glVertex3f call.

Comment: being a cube I'd be happy enough having the whole texture repeated for each face - so the coordinates you propose looks fine. I'll try that :-)

Comment: Tried that - it works fine! Cheers, P.S. -> someone should edit Adam's question to include the glTexCoords calls

Answer (score 17):

Actually there is one solution...

you can use generate texture co-ordinates like this

```
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S); //enable texture coordinate generation
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, theTexture[2]);
    glutSolidCube(2);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S); //enable texture coordinate generation
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to use this? It seems like it saved me a lot of work.

Comment: What is `theTexture` here?

Comment: Someone help me with shading. I am just used to basic functions like `glutsolidcube`. I am making a project in which I am drawing a table but I am unable to shade it. I am pasting the above code and it's not working. Please help me with this!

Comment: I tried this, but this does not work. The texture isn't on? Or should I write explicit coordinates?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [GLUT API documentation](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node80.html):

> [glutSolidCube generates] normals appropriate for lighting but do not generate texture coordinates (except for the teapot).

Comment: mmm ... maybe that's why the cube is getting the color relative to the first byte in the image

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to avoid `glBegin\End` and `GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S\T` per modern design

```
    void drawBox() {
        static glm::vec3 n[6] =
        {
          {-1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
          {0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
          {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
          {0.0, -1.0, 0.0},
          {0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
          {0.0, 0.0, -1.0}
        };
        static int faces[6][4] =
        {
          {0, 1, 2, 3},
          {3, 2, 6, 7},
          {7, 6, 5, 4},
          {4, 5, 1, 0},
          {5, 6, 2, 1},
          {7, 4, 0, 3}
        };
        glm::vec3 v[8];
        int i;

        v[0][0] = v[1][0] = v[2][0] = v[3][0] = -1;
        v[4][0] = v[5][0] = v[6][0] = v[7][0] = 1;
        v[0][1] = v[1][1] = v[4][1] = v[5][1] = -1;
        v[2][1] = v[3][1] = v[6][1] = v[7][1] = 1;
        v[0][2] = v[3][2] = v[4][2] = v[7][2] = -1;
        v[1][2] = v[2][2] = v[5][2] = v[6][2] = 1;

        auto& surface = surfaces[0];

        for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) 
                surface.normals.push_back( n[i] );
            auto i1 = i * 4;
            surface.indices.push_back( i1 + 0 );
            surface.indices.push_back( i1 + 1 );
            surface.indices.push_back( i1 + 3 );
            surface.indices.push_back( i1 + 1 );
            surface.indices.push_back( i1 + 2 );
            surface.indices.push_back( i1 + 3 );
            surface.vertices.push_back( v[faces[i][0]] );
            surface.vertices.push_back( v[faces[i][1]] );
            surface.vertices.push_back( v[faces[i][2]] );
            surface.vertices.push_back( v[faces[i][3]] );
            surface.texCoords.push_back( { 0, 0 } );
            surface.texCoords.push_back( { 0, 1 } );
            surface.texCoords.push_back( { 1, 0 } );
            surface.texCoords.push_back( { 1, 1 } );
        }
    }
```