# texture on cube-side with opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

hello i want to use a texture on a cube (created by glutsolidcube()), how can i define where the texture is pictured at?
(for example on the "frontside" of a cube)

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, filterMode);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, filterMode);

    glColor4f(0.8,0.7,0.11,1.0);
    glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(4, 1.2, 1.5);
        glTranslatef( 0, 0.025, 0);
        glutSolidCube(0.1);
    glPopMatrix();
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327043/how-to-apply-texture-to-glutsolidcube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Not possible](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node80.html), since `glutSolidCube()` only generates vertexes and normals, not texture coordinates.

However, there are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327043/how-to-apply-texture-to-glutsolidcube/327135#327135).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using glutSolidCube is impossible, as it doesn't support texturing. What I'd suggest is a tutorial that explains the process that may help you. It's a bit outdated, but NeHe's [texturing tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06) has some code that explains how to draw a cube, and the code is commented to explain which side is which for you.