# OpenGL Texture moves with camera

Tags: opengl, mapping, textures

I am applying texture to objects and its fine but when I move camera because its 3D scene then texture also moves..
Texture having lines on it is clearly visible moving..
How can I fix the texture (paste) on the objects so that it will not move with me.

Here is the Texture Code.

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); //scale linearly when image bigger than texture

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); //scale linearly when image smalled than texture
   //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);

   glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, image1->sizeX, image1->sizeY, 0,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image1->data);

    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
```

I am applying it like this on objects (its glutSolidcube)

```
glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.50f, 0.35f, 0.25f);
    glTranslated(-8, 2, -8);
    glScaled(2.8,5, 4);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S); //enable texture coordinate generation
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);


    drawhouse(0.08);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S); //enable texture coordinate generation
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
    
    glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: How did you configure texture coordinate generation? That is, how did you tell it which coordinates to generate?

Comment: I am not telling it...It is auto generating...mostly i am using it on glucylinder, glutsolidcubes and 3d cube(surface).

Comment: glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   GLUquadric* qobj2 = gluNewQuadric();
   gluQuadricTexture(qobj2, GL_TRUE);
   glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);
   gluCylinder(qobj2, 3, 1, 4, 17, 4);
   gluDeleteQuadric(qobj2);
   glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

Comment: here it is auto genrating coordinates glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S); //enable texture coordinate generation
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);

Comment: Well, it's auto-generating coordinates that aren't the ones you want, right?

Comment: Yes maybe thats'y texture is not correctly mapped due to diff size and diff coordinates..

Comment: So how are you telling it which coordinates to generate?

Comment: glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S); glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);

Comment: Yeah, that tells it to generate coordinates, it doesn't tell it which coordinates you would like it to generate. The answer is that you're not telling it which coordinates to generate. So it shouldn't be surprising that it generated the wrong ones. Who told you to use GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S/T?

Comment: I searched how to apply texture on glutSolidCube and guy here on stackoverflow answered

Comment: Here is the page https://stackoverflow.com/a/5011345/12135338

Comment: Well, it doesn't exactly work. Maybe you should render your own cube with proper texture coordinates.

Comment: I render the cube with proper coordinates but its one side is distorted and other is good