# Opengl(GLUT) Texturing one face of 3d object with 2d image C++

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, bmp, texture-mapping

Im trying to load a texture from a bmp  (loaded to imgur as bmp https://imgur.com/a/ZGscbqc   you can see it when downloaded imgur doesn't render bmp) and then display it on the front side of a object. When I try it with a solidcube the whole cube just goes a weird color and when the camera gets close to the cube my fps gets really low

I dont want to use additional libraries and here is the function to load the texture

```
GLuint LoadTexture( const char * filename )
{
  GLuint texture;
  int width, height;
  unsigned char * data;

  FILE * file;
  file = fopen( filename, "rb" );

  if ( file == NULL ) return 0;
  width = 238; //Exact dimension of my picture
  height = 419; 
  data = (unsigned char *)malloc( width * height * 3 );
  //int size = fseek(file,);
  fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
  fclose( file );

  for(int i = 0; i < width * height ; ++i)
  {
    int index = i*3;
    unsigned char B,R;
    B = data[index];
    R = data[index+2];

    data[index] = R;
    data[index+2] = B;
  }

  glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
  glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE );
  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );


  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR );
  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT );
  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT );
  gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );
  free( data );

  return texture;
}
```

and then I call it in my renderScene function

```
GLuint texture;
    texture= LoadTexture( "Princess_Peach_Stock_Art.bmp" );
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

 //princess
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-10,19,-95);
        glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
        glutSolidCube(10);
    glPopMatrix();

glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
```

2 Questions

1. How to fix this.
2. Will it be better to use 2D object like glRecd() instead of a solidcube which is 3d.

Here is a minimal repoducable code (I left the moving and the camera orientation code so that it will be easier to see and get close to it)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#define HEIGHT  20
#define WIDTH   20

GLUquadricObj *objCylinder = gluNewQuadric();
float angle=0.0,deltaAngle = 0.0,ratio;
float x=0.0f,y=1.75f,z=75.0f;
float lx=0.0f,ly=0.0f,lz=-1.0f;
int deltaMove = 0,h,w;

static GLubyte  pattern[WIDTH][HEIGHT][4]; //height, width, RGBA
unsigned char *pattern2;
static GLuint   texName[10];
unsigned long   width, height;

   GLfloat no_mat[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

   GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0 };
   GLfloat no_shininess[] = { 0.0 };
   GLfloat high_shininess[] = { 100.0 };

GLuint LoadTexture( const char * filename )
{
  GLuint texture;
  int width, height;
  unsigned char * data;

  FILE * file;
  file = fopen( filename, "rb" );

  if ( file == NULL ) return 0;
  width = 238; //Exact dimension of my picture
  height = 419;
  data = (unsigned char *)malloc( width * height * 3 );
  //int size = fseek(file,);
  fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
  fclose( file );

  for(int i = 0; i < width * height ; ++i)
  {
    int index = i*3;
    unsigned char B,R;
    B = data[index];
    R = data[index+2];

    data[index] = R;
    data[index+2] = B;
  }

  glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
  glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE );
  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );


  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR );
  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT );
  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT );
  gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );
  free( data );

  return texture;
}



void changeSize(int w1, int h1){

 if(h1 == 0)
  h1 = 1;
 w = w1;
 h = h1;
 ratio = 1.0f * w / h;
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
 gluPerspective(45,ratio,0.1,1000);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt(x, y, z, x + lx,y + ly,z + lz, 0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

 }

void setLight(void)
{
    GLfloat L0position[]={30.0, 10.0, 40.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat L1position[]={0.0, 0.0, -100.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat whitelight[]={1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat amblight[]={0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0};
    GLfloat blacklight[]={0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};

    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, amblight);
    GLfloat whitelight1[]={0, 0, 0, 1.0};

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, blacklight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, whitelight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, whitelight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, L0position);


    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
}


void orientMe(float ang) {
 lx = sin(ang);
 lz = -cos(ang);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt(x, y, z,
        x + lx,y + ly,z + lz,
     0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
}


void moveMeFlat(int i) {
 x = x + i*(lx)*0.08;
 z = z + i*(lz)*0.08;
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt(x, y, z,
        x + lx,y + ly,z + lz,
     0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
}
void renderScene(void) {

 if (deltaMove)
  moveMeFlat(deltaMove);
 if (deltaAngle) {
  angle += deltaAngle;
  orientMe(angle);
 }
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
setLight();


    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);

 glColor3f(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f);
 glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, no_mat);
   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, no_mat);
   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, no_shininess);
   glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, no_mat);
   glVertex3f(-500.0f, 0.0f, -500.0f);
   glVertex3f(-500.0f, 0.0f,  500.0f);
   glVertex3f( 500.0f, 0.0f,  500.0f);
   glVertex3f( 500.0f, 0.0f, -500.0f);
 glEnd();



GLuint texture;
    texture= LoadTexture( "Princess_Peach_Stock_Art.bmp" );
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

 //princess
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-10,19,-95);
        glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
        glutSolidCube(10);
    glPopMatrix();

glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

 glutSwapBuffers();
}


void pressKey(int key, int x, int y) {

 switch (key) {
  case GLUT_KEY_LEFT : deltaAngle = -0.001f;break;
  case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT : deltaAngle = 0.001f;break;
  case GLUT_KEY_UP : deltaMove = 1;break;
  case GLUT_KEY_DOWN : deltaMove = -1;break;
 }

}

void releaseKey(int key, int x, int y) {

 switch (key) {
  case GLUT_KEY_LEFT : if (deltaAngle < 0.0f)
         deltaAngle = 0.0f;
        break;
  case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT : if (deltaAngle > 0.0f)
         deltaAngle = 0.0f;
        break;
  case GLUT_KEY_UP :  if (deltaMove > 0)
         deltaMove = 0;
        break;
  case GLUT_KEY_DOWN : if (deltaMove < 0)
         deltaMove = 0;
        break;
 }
}


void initWindow() {
 glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(1);


 glutSpecialFunc(pressKey);
 glutSpecialUpFunc(releaseKey);

 glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
 glutIdleFunc(renderScene);

 glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
 glShadeModel (GL_SMOOTH);
 glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
 glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);


}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 glutInit(&argc, argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
 glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
 glutInitWindowSize(640,360);
 glutCreateWindow("2");

 initWindow();

 glutMainLoop();

 return(0);
}
```

Comment: OpenGL uses bitmaps, which are arrays of bytes used to represent texels (image-pixels) these are different to MS Windows .BMP files. Bmp files have a header and additionally, there may be extra bytes between the last pixel in one line of the image, and the first pixel in the next line of the image. Of course, there's also the RBG vs BGR ordering of the data for each pixel which you've encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

- `glutSolidCube` doesn't apply texture coordinates: [How to apply texture to glutSolidCube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327043/how-to-apply-texture-to-glutsolidcube)
- `fseek( file, 14+108, SEEK_CUR );` as per https://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm#MICBMP-DMYID.3
- glTexImage2D accepts `GL_BGR`: https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml
- Learning mordern C++ can be time-consuming, so it can't be a priority in this case.

Original answer:

There is really no reason not to use something like the following single-header library:
https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h

I managed to make a hint of progress in your code.
It now shows a distorted princess in a quad.

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#define HEIGHT  20
#define WIDTH   20

GLUquadricObj *objCylinder = gluNewQuadric();
float angle=0.0,deltaAngle = 0.0,ratio;
float x=0.0f,y=1.75f,z=75.0f;
float lx=0.0f,ly=0.0f,lz=-1.0f;
int deltaMove = 0,h,w;

GLuint princessTexture;

static GLubyte  pattern[WIDTH][HEIGHT][4]; //height, width, RGBA
unsigned char *pattern2;
static GLuint   texName[10];
unsigned long   width, height;

   GLfloat no_mat[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

   GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0 };
   GLfloat no_shininess[] = { 0.0 };
   GLfloat high_shininess[] = { 100.0 };

GLuint LoadTexture( const char * filename )
{
  GLuint texture;

  int width, height, nrChannels;
  unsigned char *data = stbi_load(filename, &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
  if (!data) {
    std::cout << "Couldn't load texture " << filename << " :(" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
  std::cout << width << " × " << height << ", " << nrChannels << "ch" << std::endl;

  glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
  glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE );
  //gluBuild2DMipmaps takes care of minification
  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR );
  //glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT );
  //glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT );

  gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );

  //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

  stbi_image_free(data);

  return texture;
}



void changeSize(int w1, int h1){

 if(h1 == 0)
  h1 = 1;
 w = w1;
 h = h1;
 ratio = 1.0f * w / h;
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
 gluPerspective(45,ratio,0.1,1000);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt(x, y, z, x + lx,y + ly,z + lz, 0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

 }

void setLight(void)
{
    GLfloat L0position[]={30.0, 10.0, 40.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat L1position[]={0.0, 0.0, -100.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat whitelight[]={1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat amblight[]={0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0};
    GLfloat blacklight[]={0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};

    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, amblight);
    GLfloat whitelight1[]={0, 0, 0, 1.0};

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, blacklight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, whitelight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, whitelight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, L0position);


    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
}


void orientMe(float ang) {
 lx = sin(ang);
 lz = -cos(ang);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt(x, y, z,
        x + lx,y + ly,z + lz,
     0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
}


void moveMeFlat(int i) {
 x = x + i*(lx)*0.8;
 z = z + i*(lz)*0.8;
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt(x, y, z,
        x + lx,y + ly,z + lz,
     0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
}
void renderScene(void) {

 if (deltaMove)
  moveMeFlat(deltaMove);
 if (deltaAngle) {
  angle += deltaAngle;
  orientMe(angle);
 }
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
setLight();


  glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
  glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, no_mat);
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, no_mat);
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, no_shininess);
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, no_mat);
  glColor3f(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-500.0f, 0.0f, -500.0f);
    glVertex3f(-500.0f, 0.0f,  500.0f);
    glVertex3f( 500.0f, 0.0f,  500.0f);
    glVertex3f( 500.0f, 0.0f, -500.0f);
  glEnd();

  //glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

  //princess

  glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
  glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, princessTexture);


  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(10,7,-90);
      glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glVertex3f(-5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex3f(-5.0f,-5.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex3f( 5.0f,-5.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);
    glVertex3f( 5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
  glEnd();
  glPopMatrix();

      glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
  glPushMatrix();
      glTranslatef(-5,15,-95);
      glutSolidCube(10);
  glPopMatrix();

  glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

 glutSwapBuffers();
}


void pressKey(int key, int x, int y) {

 switch (key) {
  case GLUT_KEY_LEFT : deltaAngle = -0.02f;break;
  case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT : deltaAngle = 0.02f;break;
  case GLUT_KEY_UP : deltaMove = 1;break;
  case GLUT_KEY_DOWN : deltaMove = -1;break;
 }

}

void releaseKey(int key, int x, int y) {

 switch (key) {
  case GLUT_KEY_LEFT : if (deltaAngle < 0.0f)
         deltaAngle = 0.0f;
        break;
  case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT : if (deltaAngle > 0.0f)
         deltaAngle = 0.0f;
        break;
  case GLUT_KEY_UP :  if (deltaMove > 0)
         deltaMove = 0;
        break;
  case GLUT_KEY_DOWN : if (deltaMove < 0)
         deltaMove = 0;
        break;
 }
}


void initWindow() {
 glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(1);


 glutSpecialFunc(pressKey);
 glutSpecialUpFunc(releaseKey);

 glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
 glutIdleFunc(renderScene);

 glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
 glShadeModel (GL_SMOOTH);
 glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
 glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);


}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 glutInit(&argc, argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
 glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
 glutInitWindowSize(640,360);
 glutCreateWindow("2");

 initWindow();

 princessTexture = LoadTexture("Princess_Peach_Stock_Art.png");

 glutMainLoop();

 return(0);
}
```

A piece of advice: Use up-to-date libraries and learn how to write shader code. Also, a scripting language like Python can help a lot. If its garbage collection is not an option, use modern C++.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I didn't use any library because this is a university project where we are not allowed so and use ancient unsupported stuff.

Comment: If that's the case, are the points that I added helpful?

Comment: Well they are at least I will try something other than solid cube. I didn't understand the what you meant with the line starting fseek. Thank you for helping

Comment: ```fseek``` skips the BMP header. Add it right before ```fread```.

Comment: I will try to implement it without the stb_image library thank you so much